# how to format input header file in vscode？

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Recently I have been learning cmake, and I obtained a very simple TutorialConfig.h.in file from CMake Tutorial. However, it is driving me crazy because I cannot find the right way to format it. The file contains the following:

```
// TODO the configured options and settings for Tutorial
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@

// TODO 13: use cmakedefine to define USE_MYMATH
#cmakedefine USE_MYMATH
```

When I use CMake as formatter, it runs fine but generates a warning.
[picture_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObFk1.png)

When I use C++ as formatter, I get more warnings and cannot build.
[picture_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CReNk.png)

So, guys, is there any way to make it work?

hope to get a right way to format input header file in vscode

Comment: I don't think that someone has written a formatter (or even a syntax highlight) for a **template** file. Just leave this file without a highlight and go on.

Comment: alright, thanks anyway

Comment: does the language mode not get set to C++ for files with .h.in for you (it does for me)? What do you see in the bottom right corner in the language mode indicator?

Comment: It is set to C++, but the 'format on save' option will mess everything up, to the point where it becomes unusable, shown in picture_2.

Comment: weird that formatting does that. I can't see any changes in the content- just changes in the syntax highlighting and such.